Is there a Kotlin search URL that would work with Chrome style search shortcuts?
Chromium based browsers, and tools like Surfingkeys, allow the user to set up custom quick searches, but they require a search URL with a syntax like: http://domain.tld/search?term=%s. I have quick searches like this for C++ and Python, but I want to create one for Kotlin as I start learning it to quickly look up things like the details of a class or interface. kotlinlang.org has a search feature, but it looks like the client is making async calls behind the scenes to populate the search, rather than a GET request.
Does anyone know of a Kotlin reference site that has GET requests so I can create a quick search? Search engines were no help, because they don't understand the nuance of the question, and show results about how to perform a search in Kotlin.

On kotlinlang.org, the search function mentions pressing ctrl+k to bring up the advanced search page.
On the new page, as you type in the search box, the address bar is updated with your search, revealing a search url that can be used.
Example - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html?q=read%20file&s=full
The &s=full is needed, otherwise the link will take you to the documentation page, fill out the search box with your query and display the results in the little result window.
If you are talking about specifically the API documentation at https://kotlinlang.org/api/core/kotlin-stdlib/kotlin/ - that doesn't readily reveal any kind of search url
